Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I copy my Database to FileSystemStorage?
I have used the code example to copy my included database into FileSystemStorage. The database is copied, but the Util.copy(pi, po); line throws a NullPointerException. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.
       String pathp = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("players.db").toString();
       if(pathp != null && !FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(pathp)) {
           try(InputStream pi = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/players.db");
               OutputStream po = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathp)) {
               Util.copy(pi, po);
               Util.cleanup(po);
               Util.cleanup(pi);
           } catch(IOException err) {
               Log.e(err);
           }
       }


Depends on what Util is ... But typically, a NPE comes with additional information

Either pi or po is most likely null, because the call to get the filename failed.

I suppose you need to ship your app with a database you already have. If this is the case, this line
Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/players.db");

expects your project to have players.db file in resources directory if it's a maven build or in src directory if it's a ant build
